# How to changing a property value, UIScrollView.content.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior to never from AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, swift, scrollview

I have a project built from XCode 8.3.3 and on-line a long time.
However in iOS 11, ScrollView has a new property which named contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior.
This made all scrollViewd behavior weird in Navigation.
So, I have to set the code below to all ViewController which inherent from ScrollView.

```
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        self.tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
    }
```

Since this project has lots of ViewController, is there a good way to set it in AppDelegate?

```
    UIScrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
```

I tried, but XCode warning is

```
Result of call is unused, but produces 'UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use appearance instance:

```
if #available(iOS 11, *) {
    UIScrollView.appearance().contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
}
```